# Routing a power trace from under a component

Tags: power-supply, pcb-design

I have this situation where the input of power regulation IC (LT3958) is passing from under the output diode. This input is from a 72V battery pack and is only used to enable the IC. The output current is 1A and passing through the diode.
Will routing as in the way shown in the picture cause and problem. The input trace is 6mil while the output trace is 20mil.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the suggested layout given at p.23 of the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3958fa.pdf)?

Comment: Also, (a) use ground polygons and a ground plane instead of these skinny traces. (b) your traces are not as direct as they could be. (c) avoid coming off the middle of a pad at an angle like on pad 26 and 28, this reduces clearance with the next pad and creates thin pointy features that can over-etch.

Comment: I did use a ground plane. Those five components are connected to a via which is going to a ground plane. Do I connect each and every component directly to the ground plane? 
PS: If you can't tell this is my first PCB design and I might be making many obvious mistakes @DamienD

Comment: Yes, better if each part has its own via direct to ground. If it's a non-critical part like a pull-down resistor, pad -> short trace -> via -> ground. For high-current parts like the output capacitors at the bottom, place one or two vias next to each ground pad and draw a single ground polygon that encompasses all the ground pads and all the vias (no need to draw a trace). If this is your first PCB design I recommend sticking to the suggested layout for the switching circuits!

Comment: However, note how in the suggested layout there are no vias next to the output capacitors, because the IC has a whole row of pins that are specifically means to connect the output capacitors to the IC's large ground pad, where the vias are. This is called a star ground and has the goal of putting all the power vias down to ground (for Cout, for Cin and for the chip) in a single location, so that they have the same potential.

Comment: Thank you for your replies/advices  @DamienD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the input signal is not an issue as long as you have clearance, you will have problems.

Your traces are way too thin on the caps and diode. Most buck will suggest using power planes to route the switching node with the lowest impedance as possible.

The Caps, and Diode and inductor should be placed as close as possible to the switching circuit.

The switching node has high transients at high frequencies.

You can see on the datasheet layout the recommended size of the traces/power planes:

[image]

Comment: I wanted to do it this way, but this broke my ground plane into multiple parts as I have 3 such IC's for 3 different voltage outputs and also an Arduino and sensor network. Is my decision correct or do I go for different ground planes in the same layer? @Damien

Comment: Not sure to understand your question @gautam023 but you can place your power plane on the top layer as per the datasheet.

Comment: The layout in this answer is good. Ground plane is on the other side of the board, so this doesn't break the ground plane. Copper pour on toplayer is not a ground plane.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, everyone. I see my issue was not using power planes but only traces. Though we have drifted off topic it has helped me a lot